# viewing the build errors in VS2010 is harder that VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010

in VS2008 it was easier to view the error list but in VS2010 it is writing all the errors and warnings and these other messages like debug info,... all in debug window. so sometimes I even have to do a search in debug window on the word error to find the line of error in this window..but in VS2008 they were separate and in a nice spread sheet look and feel .. is there a setting somewhere I can use to make it more similar to what it was in VS2008?
I am using VS2010 Pro with SP1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you viewing the Output window instead of the Error List?

**Ctrl+E,W** or **View->Error List** to see the Error List window.